# How can I measure the execution time of an untrusted AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Our service is invoking some Lambda functions asynchronously. These functions are written by third-party customers with carefully controlled access to helpful resources. As part of the controls on this hosting, we would like to keep a running total of the Lambda execution time and bar a customer from making further invocations if they have already exceeded their runtime quota for the day.

I see that Lambda allows you to [send invocation reports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) to other services, whether they succeed or fail. However, while the example invocation event does provide the timestamp at which the function completed, it does not provide the total execution time or any other timestamp with which to measure it:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "timestamp": "2019-11-14T18:16:05.568Z",
    "requestContext": {
        "requestId": "e4b46cbf-b738-xmpl-8880-a18cdf61200e",
        "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function:$LATEST",
        "condition": "RetriesExhausted",
        "approximateInvokeCount": 3
    },
    "requestPayload": {
        "ORDER_IDS": [
            "9e07af03-ce31-4ff3-xmpl-36dce652cb4f",
            "637de236-e7b2-464e-xmpl-baf57f86bb53",
            "a81ddca6-2c35-45c7-xmpl-c3a03a31ed15"
        ]
    },
    "responseContext": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "executedVersion": "$LATEST",
        "functionError": "Unhandled"
    },
    "responsePayload": {
        "errorMessage": "RequestId: e4b46cbf-b738-xmpl-8880-a18cdf61200e Process exited before completing request"
    }
}
```

Is there something else I can get at, perhaps with reference to one of these fields, that would yield the total execution time?

I am aware that the Lambda context argument provides a timer that says how much execution time is left, and that the Lambda can also be timed internally. However, since the code is not written by us, I cannot trust that it will call on these features or report the results honestly.

Comment: You don't control the code, but do you control access to the logging?  there'll be a log message for the end of each request that provides runtime (though you'd have to sum them yourself)

Comment: @erik258 Yes, I do control the logging and would be able to see it in Cloudwatch. That might work, though it seems like I would need to have a Cloudwatch alarm that goes off for every single execution report and send it to an SNS topic that could read the execution data, which seems imposing. It can also take between 5 and 10 minutes for the data to show up in Cloudwatch - if at all feasible, I would prefer something faster.

Comment: Couldn't find a way to pick up a function end event with EventBridge.  Couldn't find a way to pick up a log event that way either, for what it's worth.  You don't need to set an alarm though; you could use a [Subscription Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) directly to a "tally up the time" lambda.  " It can also take between 5 and 10 minutes for the data to show up in Cloudwatch" That's worst case scenario.  It *can*, but it almost never does.  I immediately read the logs when I'm debugging lambdas all the time.